# Issues getting a background image to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am unsure of why I cannot get a `background-image` to appear in the following snippet. The url is correct and I have set size to the image. Also, how can you align a background-image in the center of a page? I know there are properties like `right top`, but I do not see one for center vertically and horizontally.

Thanks.

```js
$("#arrow-icon").slideToggle(1000);
```

```css
.arrow {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
#arrow-icon {
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: none;
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/down-arrow.ico");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow">
  <div id="arrow-icon">
   <!-- <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/down-arrow.ico"> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the div is smaller that the picture.
You can get around this with the background-size property

Example:

```
#arrow-icon {
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: none;
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/down-arrow.ico");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

fiddle - https://fiddle.jshell.net/800modgt/

Or you can change the div width and height to the image width and height...

Comment: Well I'm trying to use the width and height to resize the image, but I want to do it proportionally.

Comment: you can use background-size:100% auto;

Comment: Awesome. Why isn't the `padding-top` working? Ideally I want this in the center of the page, which justin's `margin:auto;` helped align it center horizontally. I just want to be able to know how I can movie it down vertically,

Comment: IF I do this: ` position: relative;
    top: 100px;` the arrow goes down, but then some of it gets cut out again.

Comment: just remove the padding-top, it alters the div height

Comment: Then how can I move the div down without altering the arrows height?>

Comment: you did it right with the "position: relative; top: 100px;"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101485/discussion-between-binaryghost-and-becky).

Answer (score 1):

And in terms of centering, simply use:

```
background-position: center;
```

That said, I'm noticing that it's not center on the page on the Fiddle previously posts. You can use

```
margin:auto;
```

to center a `<div>` horizontally

You might consider for the positioning using CSS3 for positioning, as it's very versatile in changing position of a div and how far it slides out. Here is a JSFiddle. It's for side animation, but it will work for just a standard up/down, too.

https://jsbin.com/yovaqo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Why doesn't the padding push the image down?

Comment: It looks like BinaryGhost has you covered. Just in case you want more versatility, I might consider toggling, but having CSS3 do all the positioning, as it tends to be more eloquent. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the info!